# I get a Promise instead of a collection therefore error -> [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}:

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have this factory:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('appContacts')
        .factory('dataService', ['$q', '$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($q, $http) {

        return {
            getAllOrganizations: getAllOrganizations,
            getAllContacts: getAllContacts,
        };

        function getAllContacts() {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/allcontacts'
            })
        }

        function getAllOrganizations() {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/organizations'
            })
        }
    }

})();
```

And I have this Controller:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('appContacts')
        .controller('contactsController', function contactsController($http, dataService) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.organizations = [];
            vm.allcontacts = [];

            vm.organizations = dataService.getAllOrganizations(); 
            vm.allcontacts = dataService.getAllContacts(); 

    });

})();
```

If I make a console.log in the controller like
console.log(dataService.getAllOrganizations()) and console.log(dataService.getAllContacts()) I see I have a **PROMISE** therefore I get an error like 
*[filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}:*

How could I convert this promise in a real error that I could assign to the variables like:

**vm.organizations = dataService.getAllOrganizations()**

and

**vm.allcontacts = dataService.getAllContacts();** 
?

Comment: This is just a "double-barrelled" version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/30180679#30180679.

Answer (score 0):

Your services return with promise. So, you need to resolve the promise using **then** syntax in the controller in order to get the data from your server. You need something like this:

```
dataService.getAllOrganizations().then(function(result){
  vm.organizations = result;
}, function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

In order to having your calls by default you need a method, let's call it activate(). I'm not sure the syntax is correct, I wrote it top of my head.

Please check John Papa's style guide [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('appContacts')
        .controller('contactsController', function contactsController($http, dataService) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.organizations = [];
            vm.allcontacts = [];

            var activate = function activate() {
              dataService.getAllOrganizations().then(function(result){
                vm.organizations = result;
              }, function (error){});

              dataService.getAllContacts().then(function(result){
                vm.allcontacts = result;
              }, function (error){});
            }

            activate();

    });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am moving ahead, but now I have an slightly different error:

Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {"data":[{"id":"5","dateCreated":"2:... and so on with the whole returned data. 
I will have to read the John Papa's style guide